# Can the Community Bot behavior be made less annoying?

Tags: discussion, support

Am I the only one who finds the Community Bot behavior in the robotics group very annoying?

- It's annoying that it promotes so many ancient posts. The majority of these ros posts prior to ~2018 are not relevant.
- Due to the migration from answers.ros.org, most of these posts don't have the original author registered on stackexchange, so they will never get green-checked. Does this mean we're going to be forced to see obsolete questions recycle forever?

What would be maybe useful is bumping posts: 1) with exactly 0 answers, and 2) question created/edited less than 6 months ago.

Do we have any influence over the Community Bot's selection algorithm for this group?

Comment: I'll have to look into this more if there's options to influence it.

Answer (score 2):

To quote [Shog9's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184511/280335) to [Community ♦ seems to be bumping new questions more frequently than usual](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184485/280335) over on Meta.SE:

> Note that the posts eligible for bumping are those scoring >= 0 that have gone at least 30 days with no activity, have at least one non-deleted answer scoring 0 and none scoring more than that, and no accepted answer (also, they can't be deleted or closed).

Comment: Yup, I think that's it. So, if it has an answer and it answers the question, give it an upvote and it won't get bumped again. If it has an answer that doesn't answer the question then downvote the answer and/or post an answer that does provide a solution.

Comment: Yeah, that seems about it... over on 3D Printing we have bumped questions that keep reappearing, so annoying. For example [this one](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/posts/15434/revisions), and you can see that it was constantly bumped, until I just gave in and upvoted 0scar's nice answer in Feb - hopefully that will stop further bumping - only time will tell :-)

Comment: For me, it's not so bad anymore. The conversion from ROS answers has brought a **FLOOD** of new traffic, but it definitely used to be tumbleweeds around here, seeing the same dozen or so questions come in with the tides :joy:

Comment: The voting to get them out of that state is good to do to help resolve them. If they go up they're helpful and if they stay unresolved I think they will be pruned too. PS there likely going to be more traffic soon when we finally get redirects setup from the ROS answers archive. More people not more questions though.

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to find the source on the statement I'm going to make, but I believe the rule is that questions get bumped if there is no accepted answer and there are no answers with a positive score.

If you're seeing questions get bumped that have a good answer, *upvote the answer.* If you see a question that's bumped that does not have a good answer, please *add a good answer.*

If you see a question that gets bumped that is a bad question, please vote to close the question or flag it for moderator review if you don't have enough reputation to cast a close vote.

Comment: The source that you *might* be referring to is [Shog9's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184511/280335) to [Community ♦ seems to be bumping new questions more frequently than usual](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184485/280335).